# JSON Object javascript, how to get value not key

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have an JSON object in javascript

```
"urls": {"url": "http://www.google.co.uk"}
```

I want to be able to get the actual URL google.co.uk, not the text 'url'.

I also have a variable called date.

I want to create a New object that holds the url value as the **key** and set the value to the date '20/10/2013' for example.

```
"newObject": {"http://www.google.co.uk": "20/10/2013"}
```

Im sure this is possible however I am not so good with json objects and i welcome any help.

Comment: your syntax is a little off. Are these complete objects?

Comment: This is a bit confusing as neither of your snippets are valid JSON.  Is `urls` an object property, or the name of your Javascript variable?  Same question for `newObject` -- do you want one of the object properties to be `newObject`, or is that just what you want the name of the variable to be?

Comment: urls and newObject are the names of the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, you should create a readable array like this

```
var myArray = [
  { url: "http://www.google.co.uk", date: "20/10/2013"},
  { url: "http://www.google.com", date: "20/10/2014" }
]
```

then you can parse all elements using a for loop for each object in the array.

```
var myObject;
var url, date;
for(var k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++)
    myObject = myArray[k];
    url = myObject.url;
    date = myObject.date;
}
```

If you need speed you can use a Memoization Pattern or create hashes to get O(1) queries.

Comment: Shouldn't use a `for ... in ...` loop on an array.

Comment: You should use a "normal" `for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)` loop here.  `for..in` is not meant to be used on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

To get the URL, you just have yo do :

```
var myURL = urls.url;
```

Then to get the date :

```
var myDate = newObject[myURL];
```

Comment: Would that then associate a url with a particular date?

Comment: @Joe could you explain more what you mean? If you have the URL, you can have the date.

Comment: Do you know much about google drive api using javascript? I am currently stuck retreiving picture URLs